# Check if service is running in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I am writing a service which checks if a particular service is running. I am calling the checkService.class using the alarm Manager for every second. (This works just fine)

In checkService.class I have the following code:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() 
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
    {
        if (PhoneListnerService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When it returns true, I don't do anything. When false I start the service PhoneListnerService.class. This process works just fine the first time, but if I kill the whole application using some taskKiller application - The "isMyserviceRunning" still shows **true**.

I believe taskKiller kills all the services, BroadCastreceivers etc - if so how come it is showing **True** instead of showing **False**?

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: not even at one point did it return false?

Comment: Nope. I am trying this on my Nexus 5

Comment: Dont expect your application to work properly if you kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe android isn't done stopping the service. Killing services have undefined behaviour. On the other hand you don't have to check if service is running before starting it. You can use that alarm to start the service instead. If the service is already running, `onCreate` isn't called but `onStartCommand` is. What you can do is put a variable in the intent when starting the service from alarm, check for the variable in the `onStartCommand` and use some simple logic to figure out what to do.

Comment: Are you saying Task Killer is not killing the services properly?

Comment: @TheDevMan  I am saying the only way to guarantee that the service was stopped successfully is by calling `stopService`or `stopSelf`. Like I said, force stopping tasks and services can behave irrationally and can't be trusted. Force stopping will only send the signal to the process, everything else is taken care of by the OS.

Comment: @TheDevMan : Who knows what the task killer is doing? Task killers are evil and go against Android design principles and people who write them have no regard for those principles. If you want to test completely shutting down your app then go to Settings -> Apps and use 'Force Stop'. At least you'll know it's the Android OS which has killed your app and not a task killer which may or may not succeed in what it's claimed it can do.

Comment: @Squonk : I tried the force close part.. The alarmManager didn't work at all

Comment: If I stop and start the service every five seconds. Does it drain my battery?

Comment: @TheDevMan : You are approaching this in the wrong way. If you want to test to see if your code in your question works or not then put a test 'Stop' button into your app and use it to manually stop your `Service` then use logging to check it is correctly stopped and then started again. You haven't really explained what your `Service` does and why you need to constantly check its state so it is very difficult to advise you on what to do.

Comment: I have created a broadReciever that looks for screenOFF and ScreenON and keeps a note on this. BroadCastReceiver is controlled through a service... So if a taskKiller kills the application I am not able to detect it because the service and receiver is stopped and hence to start the service I am trying out difference ways.

Comment: continued from previous comment... One is to start_Sticky which works just fine for version below 4.4.2 and to solve the issue with 4.4.2 - I am trying out alarmManager that checks if service is off if so Start it or else don't..

Answer (score 0):

@TheDevMan may be you are right or wrong but main thing is here you use alarm manager so when you kill your service it is restarted by alarmmanager with in a second. so it is return true.check it.

Comment: from the question, the alarm manager checks if the service is running before starting the service

Comment: I logged and checked it for 10 seconds. It is the same problem.